# get an data member values using FieldInfo class

Tags: c#, generics, collections

```
class Algo
{
    public const long AlgorithmDescription = 1611048;
    public const long AlgorithmFamilyCodeSequence = 6684719;
    public const long AlgorithmName = 6684726;
    public const long AlgorithmNameCodeSequence = 6684720;
    public const long AlgorithmParameters = 6684722;
    public const long AlgorithmType = 1611047;
    public const long AlgorithmVersion = 6684721;
}
class Class1<T>
{
    SortedList<uint, string> ds;
    public SortedList<uint, string> TraverseTag()
    {
        ds = new SortedList<uint, string>();
        uint i = 0;
        foreach (FieldInfo prop in typeof(Algo).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                          BindingFlags.Static | 
                                                          BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            ds.Add(i, prop.Name);
            i++;
        }
        return ds;
     }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var objClass = new Class1();
        SortedList<uint, string> s = objClass.TraverseTag();
    }
}
```

From `Algo` class, I create a dll for that and use reference to my `Program.cs` class and call the `TraverseTag()` method, this method returns me uint and FieldInfo it returns me `{[0,AlgorithmDescription]}` but also I want the values that are assigned to my data member in `Algo` class.

For example>

> {[0,AlgorithmDescription,1611048]}

Comment: Minor observation: `Algo` would work well as an `enum Algo : long {...}`

Comment: @MarcGravell Algo is an dll I cant edit it i just mention the scenario....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to a [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx) method of the FieldInfo instance. That should give you the value of that field for a specific instance of the class to which the field belongs to.

Comment: I refer msdn link that correct but in the msdn second example there is constructor of myclass but my algo class having no constructor so how can i do that

Comment: @user2404595 pass `null` as the instance, because `const` fields are `static`